# Split names and create matrix in R

Tags: r

I have this data:

```
names <- c("Baker, Chet", "Jarret, Keith", "Miles Davis")
```

I want to manipulate it so the first name come first, so i split it:

```
names <- strsplit(names, ", ")

[[1]]
[1] "Baker" "Chet"

[[2]]
[1] "Jarret" "Keith"

[[3]]
[1] "Miles Davis"
```

The problem is that, when i want to put them together, the name `"Miles Davis"` will come out wrong, because it is already the `full name`.

```
matrix(unlist(names), ncol=2, byrow = TRUE)

     [,1]          [,2]    
[1,] "Baker"       "Chet" 
[2,] "Jarret"      "Keith"
[3,] "Miles Davis" "Baker"
```

What should i do to create a new `df` that will look like this:

```
"Chet Baker"
"Keith Jarret"
"Miles Davis"
```

Here's the reference: http://rfunction.com/archives/1499

Comment: Miles Davis doesn't have the comma separator

Comment: Use `names <- strsplit(names, ",\\s*|\\s+")` instead

Comment: i know that... that's why i'm asking =))) @skrubber

Comment: @docendodiscimus thank you, but i dont think the regex will help this way. I just need a way to gather them together after the strsplit and create a new df with the names binded

Comment: Well then you need to tell us what kind of logic you want to use and what the end result should look like.

Comment: Are you saying "Miles Davis" is **the** `FirstName` and `Surname` is missing? Please clarify your expected output.

Comment: Sorry! I've just edited, i hope i've made myself clear now =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily adapt the pattern used in the regular expression so that it matches either a comma followed by 0+ spaces or 1+ spaces:

```
names <- strsplit(names, ",\\s*|\\s+")
matrix(unlist(names), ncol=2, byrow = TRUE)
#     [,1]     [,2]   
#[1,] "Baker"  "Chet" 
#[2,] "Jarret" "Keith"
#[3,] "Miles"  "Davis"
```

---

Since the desired result is different than initially described, heres's a different approach:

```
names <- strsplit(names, ",\\s*")
data.frame(name = sapply(names, function(x) paste(rev(x), collapse = " ")))
#          name
#1   Chet Baker
#2 Keith Jarret
#3  Miles Davis
```

---

Another option, using capture groups in a regular expression to swap everything before the comma with everything after the comma and replace the comma with a space.

```
names <- c("Baker, Chet", "Jarret, Keith", "Miles Davis")
sub("([^,]+),\\s*([^,]+)$", "\\2 \\1", names)
#[1] "Chet Baker"   "Keith Jarret" "Miles Davis"
```

Comment: Thank you! But i've edited the question, and the answer you gave me wouldn't do it...

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot! =))

Answer (score 3):

Another *regex* solution:

```
gsub("(\\w+), (\\w+)", "\\2 \\1", names)
# [1] "Chet Baker"   "Keith Jarret" "Miles Davis"
```